# Get values of an inline result in org-mode

Tags: org-mode, org-babel

I like the short notation of org-babel function calls. E.g. you can define a named code block like this

```
#+name: get_date
#+begin_src http
GET http://date.jsontest.com
#+end_src
```

and then hit C-c C-c in some inline call to get the results for some parameters (if it's a single line result that is):

```
call_get_date[:select ".date"]() {{{results(=12-06-2016=)}}}
```

Or you can even do the code definition inline thus getting rid of 4 more lines:

```
src_http[:select ".date"]{GET http://date.jsontest.com} {{{results(=12-06-2016=)}}}
```

I find that is pretty cool, and I would like to use it more often. But I don't see a way to set a name for the inline result to reference it for later `:var` assignments. Is there any? Or is there some simple elisp which could be employed here?

Comment: "Inline code blocks don't associate themselves with their results, they are only expected to be evaluated during export" (http://org-babel.readthedocs.io/en/latest/eval/#inline-code-blocks)

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know that documentation. Then it seems I've to write my elisp for that. I'm not so much interested in the export in this case, because I just want to automate some maintenance tasks. I guess this shows that org-babel is heavily build upon the needs of the research community, not so much on developers and administrators.

Answer (score 2):

(Not a solution, just digging into the problem.)

One can actually assign a name to an intermediate result with `#+name:`

```
#+name: callgetdate
call_get_date[:select .date]()
```

then the result will be tagged with the name, and a later `call_callgetdate()` will not complain/give an error. ***BUT*** in my tests, this later call always gave `nil` results. Idem for the `src_` case.

I think this is a bug/irregularity in org.

The same happened for me with the longer version of `#+call:`.

```
#+name: callgetdate2
#+call: get_date[:select .date]
#+RESULTS: callgetdate2
# ... The expected json date ...
```

but:

```
call_callgetdate2()
#+RESULTS:
: nil
```

So this is not only related to inline blocks.

Answer (score 0):

Might be a little late to add something, but here is the solution which is working for me. One can just put a `#+results: somename` header in front of the paragraph containing the inline result. The following elisp function can then be used to extract the value:

```
(defun get-inline-result (name)
  (save-excursion
    (org-babel-goto-named-result name)
    (re-search-forward "{{{results(=\\(.*?\\)=)}}}")
    (match-string 1)))
```

If you have more than one inline result per paragraph I guess you're still stuck or you have come up with an own inline-naming syntax and a corresponding elisp function to match it.